# Failing to install dependencies with sdkmanager inside a Dockerfile

Tags: android, flutter, docker, dockerfile, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to package the dependencies to build an Android application inside a Docker container. As part of the dependencies installation, I'm using [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) to install some dependencies. When specifying a list of packages to install, it requires to put their names in double quotes. Since also Docker's [RUN in exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) requires to put double quotes around its arguments, I'm using double double-quotes and escaping the inner ones like this:

```
RUN ["./android-sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager", "--sdk_root=/root/android-sdk", "--install", "\"build-tools;33.0.2\"", "\"platform-tools\"", "\"ndk;21.4.7075529\"", "\"cmake;3.6.4111459\""]
```

However, when I try to build my image I get the following error:

```
Step 12/20 : RUN ["./android-sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager", "--sdk_root=/root/android-sdk", "--install", "\"build-tools;33.0.2\"", "\"platform-tools\"", "\"ndk;21.4.7075529\"", "\"cmake;3.6.4111459\""]
 ---> Running in 269b0033b9af
Warning: Failed to find package '"build-tools;33.0.2"'                          
The command './android-sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/root/android-sdk --install "build-tools;33.0.2" "platform-tools" "ndk;21.4.7075529" "cmake;3.6.4111459"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I instead don't put the double double-quotes, I don't get any errors, but I think it's not installing all the dependencies as later Flutter complains about not finding the Android SDK in the root I specified, and indeed I can't find there e.g. the `platform-tools` directory. What am I doing wrong? Do you know a better way to install Android SDK inside a container?
You can find the full Dockerfile [here](https://pastebin.com/CE2qwLwy).
Thank you for your help.

Update: trying to manually install dependencies witb sdkmanager inside the container, I found out that to install them you first need to manually accept a license agreement and then after installing them flutter still doesn't recognize my installation. Maybe it is too difficult to install the Android SDK inside a container and I should just use [this Docker image](https://github.com/thyrlian/AndroidSDK) that runs an sdk from your host or just build the app on my host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved by basing my image on [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/androidsdk/android-31) and using the "normal" syntax for run like this:

```
RUN sdkmanager --install "build-tools;33.0.2" "cmdline-tools;latest" "ndk;21.4.7075529" "platform-tools" "cmake;3.6.4111459"
```